# PHPExcel Не выводится изображение в колонтитуле

Tags: изображения, phpexcel

Пытаюсь использовать шаблон .xlsx, в котором уже есть колонтитулы, верхний и нижний.

Загружаю файл, далее сразу выдаю новый:

```
/* путь к файлу верный */
$pExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($path);
$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5($pExcel);
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="myxls.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

В колонтитуле отображается текст, но изображения нет.

Если поставить в коде вывод и посмотреть, что показывается по изображениям, то все верно.

Код:

```
var_dump($aSheet->getHeaderFooter()->getImages());
```

Вывод:

```
array (size=1)
  'LH' => 
    object(PHPExcel_Worksheet_HeaderFooterDrawing)[1057]
      private '_path' => string 'zip://D:\JENTEK\mebs\trunk\application/../www/files/load.xlsx#xl/media/image1.png' (length=81)
      protected '_name' => string 'mebs_logo_excel' (length=15)
      protected '_offsetX' => string '0' (length=1)
      protected '_offsetY' => string '0' (length=1)
      protected '_width' => int 112
      protected '_height' => int 145
      protected '_resizeProportional' => boolean true
      private '_imageIndex' (PHPExcel_Worksheet_BaseDrawing) => int 0
      protected '_description' => null
      protected '_worksheet' => null
      protected '_coordinates' => null
      protected '_rotation' => null
      protected '_shadow' => null
      private '_path' (PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing) => null
```

Однако данного изображения в сгенерированном файле нет.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему так?

Answer (score 1):

В общем нашел, как исправить данную проблему.
Может кому будет полезно.

Проблема не появления изображения в колонтитулах была в том, что использовал вот этот класс - `PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5` (для создания эксель файла), а загружал из файла `load.xlsx` (более новой версии Excel).

Получалось, что я загружал файл Excel 2007-2010 года, а генерировал файл 97-2003 года.

На всякий случай обновил библиотеку phpExcel с офиц. сайта и сгенерировал файл через класс `PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007`().

Всё сработало. Изображения в колонтитулах отображаются.